# Why can't I pass a variable to Model's constructor in Code Igniter?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

It seems that it is impossible to pass a variable to a Model's Constructor in Code Igniter. Maybe I'm missing something in MVC or Code Igniter, but I don't understand what.

In my case, should I use librairies instead of Model ? (librairies actually accept parameters)

Actually my code is looking like this, and I think it's a bit strange :

Controller :

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function user($user_id) {
        $this->load->model('user');
        $this->user->setId($user_id);

        $data['username'] = $this->user->getName();     
        // Isn't it a bit strange ? I can load the class User even if the User doesn't mean anything ?
    }
}
```

Model :

```
class User extends CI_Model {
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
        // Retrieve data from DB...
        $this->name = $retrieved_data['name'];
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you rename your model class to, say, user_model?

Comment: it's exactly the same thing. In fact, the problem is that Model in Code Igniter doesn't accept variables for constructor (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html). I don't know if it's normal or if I'm just missing something in CodeIgniter Logic (or maybe MVC Logic ? Does Model should not accept any variable in its constructor ?)

Comment: It should accept variables ... hm, what errors do you get?
I'll rewrite this for you.

Comment: You can't have two identical class names in PHP, even though you're using CodeIgniter. I'm surprised you even got the model to load. You aren't actually "passing a variable to a Model's Constructor" in this code either.

Comment: @Madmartigan You are right, sorry. I simplified my code for stackoverflow but in my "real" code, it was User**s** and User, that's why it was working :)

Comment: @Shomz Your answer made me understand the conception of model in CodeIgniter. In fact, i was trying to do something like $this->load->model('user',THE_USER_ID); but it's seems model should not work like real objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Controller:

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function user($user_id) {
        $this->load->model('user_model');

        $data['username'] = $this->user_model->getName($user_id);     
    }
}
```

Model:

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public function getName($user_id) {
        //Retrieve data from DB using the $user_id variable...
        return $retrieved_data['name'];
    }
}
```

Seems like a more logical and faster way to do it. Not sure if it complies with the rest of your code, but it might help you track down the errors.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I understand a lot better now. But I have another question, related with what you wrote : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069903/real-objects-and-mvc

Comment: Glad I could help! As for that question, think of CI as one huuuge object.