# Real objects and MVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, instantiation

Until there, I always coded object this way :

```
// initialization
$husband = new User('Bob');
$wife = new User('Sarah');

// action
$husband->dance();
$wife->read();

// get
echo "The husband is ".$husband->getAge()." years old";
```

But with CodeIgniter (and MVC), it seems it's better to think this way :

```
// load model
$this->load->model('user');

// action
$this->user->dance('Bob');
$this->user->read('Sarah');

// get
echo $this->user->getAge('Bob');
```

But in this case, how to deal with "real objects" ? For example the object "Bob" and the object "Sarah" ?
Maybe i'm missing something but it seems for me that Model (second example) != Object (first example).
Do this conception of objects are incompatibles ?

I have the directory view, the directory controller, and the directory model. Should I have also a "objects" directory ?

Comment: If you need a framework that don't teach you bad practices (like using Singleton anti-pattern), you don't have many options: [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) microframework, or [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/) framework. You won't regret moving to one of them. Even if  you end up using something else, the best practices learned when reading their documentation will already be worth the effort.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper Silex seems a little bit too light for my project, and Symfony too huge... What do you think about Kohana ? Does it also teach bad practices ? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I haven't digged into Kohana, but since it was originally based on CI, I wouldn't expect too much. You should use whichever framework you think will be best for your project (even CI), and in parallel learn Sf2 for future projects, or just for the sake of learning good practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to use CI, you can do this:

```
// load the class. I think there was a second parameter to avoid instantiation, not sure though. Either way, this will at least load the class
$this->load->model('user',false);

$husband = new User('Bob');
$wife = new User('Sarah');

// action
$husband->dance();
$wife->read();
```

This is still MVC. The ugly class loading part is there because CI does not have class autoloading on referenciation, so you have to do it manually. Maybe you can integrate a [Universal Class Loader](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php) somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter is based around the **[Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)**.

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern used to implement the mathematical concept of a singleton, by **restricting the instantiation of a class to one object**. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system. The concept is sometimes generalized to systems that operate more efficiently when only one object exists, or that restrict the instantiation to a certain number of objects.

Comment: And singleton becomes wraith if it is not used properly, and this is a common mistake. True for me also :-(

Comment: @Kowser: Actually, singleton is an anti-pattern: it can't be used properly.

Comment: Wow. Just discover what Singleton is. Thank you very much ! But now, what shoud I do ? Create a "Objects" directory or change for another PHP Framework without Singleton ? o_O

Comment: @user1014813 if you are keen enough to learn another framework which is easy, it is kohana. I had to give up Codeigniter doing my first project, it was horrible experience for me. But obviously this is my opinion.